# fiddle working, real page not in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, header

I have a problem, but I'm not sure why:p I'm trying to make an online form, and I have been having some problems with the css implementation in IE9. So far my page is working (the divs are displaying as in-line block) in chrome, but not IE9. However, when I put the exact same code in fiddle, it also works in IE9 http://jsfiddle.net/XuD6j/1/

This makes me think that I might have some possible problem in the header. This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title> Registratieformulier Peuters</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="generator" content="syn">
<style type="text/css"></style>
<link href="http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/print.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
</head>
```

If you have any ideas please let me know, also if you think the problem can't be in the header, but should be somewhere else.
thanks in advance!

Comment: Works fine in IE10 under IE9 mode from what I can see.

Comment: It works in the fiddle, but not on the actual page: http://www.doenwatikkan.nl/jeroen/login.php
Sorry, text is in Dutch, but if you click the button on the first page you'll see what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your doctype looks wrong, this is probably forcing IE into [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode), try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

as recommended by http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

**Update**

It's defo a quirks mode issue, press F12 and look at the **Browser mode**. Your code appears to render the below in the header which I think is the issue:

```
Notice: Undefined index: route in /home/doenwa01/domains/doenwatikkan.nl/public_html/jeroen/verwerking.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: ID in /home/doenwa01/domains/doenwatikkan.nl/public_html/jeroen/verwerking.php on line 8
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

**More updates**

your source now seems to contain two doctypes:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>

<head>
```

if you load you page and click view source you'll see the issue, basically you want to end up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
```

Comment: I was looking for this article and you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @Liam: Thanks, I changed the doctype, but unfortunately it's still not displaying correctly

Comment: As page default it indeed says quirks mode, and when I change it to IE9 default it shows up correctly, so that's great! But how can I change the page default then? Doctype should be all the way at the top of the document, right?

Comment: It's the errors at the top of your page, see code above. Remove these and it should be fine

Comment: okay, I turned off error reporting, but now it's showing my doctype as a comment, while I don't have that in my code:S any clue why?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's your doctype, currently it's commented out and in the wrong place. Quirks mode is forced when you don't have a doctype (in the correct place).

You want it at the very top of the page, this is the HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**EDIT:** You have some errors at the top of your page, if you remove them it should work fine.

```
<!-- Created: 01-23-09 13:49:39 by R.Haenbeukers -->



Notice: Undefined index: route in /home/doenwa01/domains/doenwatikkan.nl/public_html/jeroen/verwerking.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: ID in /home/doenwa01/domains/doenwatikkan.nl/public_html/jeroen/verwerking.php on line 8
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
```